# German €9 ticket for trains: who's eligible, and what's the catch?

Tags: trains, public-transport, germany

I saw that the German government is offering a special €9 train ticket for a month. I still have some doubts:

- Is this as good as it sounds? No trick? No additional fee?
- Are tourists allowed to buy this too?
- Are trains that accept them going to be totally packed or not available due to overcrowding?
- Can a family plan a whole trip around them? I'm aware they exclude certain higher speed trains, but they still seem like a steal for, say, visiting a region like Cologne, Bonn, Dusseldorf and travel between these cities and within the city.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the 9€ ticket was conceived as a subsidy measure to help people cope with the rising gas prices. It's supposed to motivate people to use public transportation more.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136796/discussion-on-question-by-quora-feans-german-9-ticket-for-trains-whos-eligibl).

Answer (score 60):

> - Is this as good as it sound? No trick? No additional fee?

Yes, no tricks, no additional fee. However, it is only valid in regional trains, not in long-distance trains like IC, EC, ICE, night trains, and Flixtrain.

> - Are tourists allowed to buy this too?

Yes.

> - Are trains that accept them going to be totally packed or not available due to overcrowding?

Especially on weekends and during summer holiday time (which is July and August) you can expect especially trains in tourist regions to be packed (e.g. the trains to Sylt, probably also trains in the Alps region and around bigger cities)

> - Can a family plan a whole trip around them? I'm aware they exclude certain higher speed trains, but they still seem like a steal for, say, visiting a region like Cologne, Bonn, Dusseldorf and travel between these cities and within the city.

A family can certainly plan a trip around them, with the limitations that you already mentioned. If you e.g. take a long-distance train with a separate ticket to the Cologne region, you can then use the 9-Euro-ticket to take buses, trams, subway, etc. around those cities and the region.

Personally, I wouldn't use the ticket to do longer trips, since by only using regional trains you would travel for several hours and have to change trains more often (e.g. from Frankfurt to Berlin it would take around 9 hours, instead of 4 hours with a direct ICE train).

A little bit more explanation about the fact that Mark already mentioned in [his answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/173979/15182): some IC trains are also classified as regional trains. As Mark mentioned, in those trains, the 9-Euro-Ticket is usually not valid, however (to add even more confusion), DB has reached an agreement with some states for some of those connections, so that the 9-Euro-Ticket is valid.

One example of such a train, where the ticket is valid:

[image: 9-Euro ticket valid connection]

Unfortunately, the relevant description is not translated, it's this sentence:

> Das 9-Euro-Ticket ist in allen RE-Zügen der DB Fernverkehr AG Stuttgart, Singen und Konstanz gültig

which means

> The 9-Euro-Ticket is valid in all RE trains of DB Fernverkehr AG between Stuttgart, Singen and Konstanz

Another example, where the 9-Euro ticket is not valid on such a train:

[image: 9-Euro ticket not valid]

Again, the relevant description is not translated, it's the sentence:

> Das 9-Euro-Ticket ist in diesem RE der DB Fernverkehr AG nicht gültig

which means

> The 9-Euro-Ticket is not valid in this RE of DB Fernverkehr

You can also check a specific connection if the 9-Euro-Ticket is offered. E.g. in my first example, if you click on the 9 Euro price offer, you see that it's that specific ticket which is offered for that connection, and then the 9-Euro-ticket is valid. If it's not offered for a specific connection, it's not valid (like in the second example, where the 9-Euro-ticket is not offered for the RE train).

The screenshots are taken from [the German rail planner](https://www.bahn.com/en), which is one of the better train planners in Europe, available in several languages.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the screenshots, I think this will help a  lot of people.

Comment: Might be helpful to put big red arrows on the pics to show where the restrictions are.

Comment: @o.m. I found it in like 8 seconds even far from my monitor about 39 inches...

Answer (score 13):

A few extra notes on this topic:

This offer, by the federal goverment (who does not supply the services), was made **without previous consultations** with the companies that are expected to meet a higher demand at a very short notice.

The city transports, for the most part, have a good idea what to expect.

But for regional trains, on a suddenly sunny weekend, problems should be expected.

---

Each ticket is valid for a specific calender month

- printed on the ticket as: **Juni**, **Juli** or **August**
- they can be bought at any time (I bought all 3 at once)

You must write your name on the ticket and be prepared to show an ID with that name. (i.e. the tickets are **not** transferable to other persons)

There are a few Regional trains where the ticket is **not** valid (organized by 'DB Fernverkehr AG' that normaly offers IC trains, but due to low demand are classifying them as regional trains). This will cause confusion.

---

The text from the original anouncement in March:

> [2022-03-22: Energiepreise: Ampel beschließt 300 Euro Einmalzahlung – Tanken wird günstiger | ZEIT ONLINE](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2022-03/energiepreise-ampel-beschliesst-300-euro-steuerliche-energiepauschale)
> ...
> As a **further measure** to relieve the burden on citizens, Ricarda Lang announced **support for people who depend on local public transport**: here, *tickets for nine euros per month* should be available nationwide – also for a limited period of three months, she said.
> ...

Comment: In my opinion, you should stress the last part more, and also how to find it. Usually when checking a connection on bahn.de and expanding on the trains, it should say there, if it is not valid.

Comment: @infinitezero I am simply passing on the information made available in the local press. Based on the present information available, the applications (presently) cannot distinguish this (up to now it wasn't needed). How the Deutsche Bahn will deal this is presently unknown, but they are obviously aware of the problem.

Comment: I added some examples with screenshots in my answer, that might help a little bit with this specific case.

Comment: Does this have the same restrictions as the Länder-Ticket, which give unlimited train travel for one day, at €22? These are restricted to one Land (region), there are 16 of them.   If so, it's an incredibly good offer

https://www.bahn.com/en/offers/regional/regional-day-tickets

Comment: @CSM The offers are similar but without the time restriction on weekdays that the Länder-Ticket have.

Comment: You can also use the DB Navigator app to buy the ticket on your phone.

Comment: Nitpick: 'organized by *DB Fernverkehr AG* that normaly offers IC trains, but due to low demand are classifying them as regional trains' -- this is not true. These trains are classified as regional trains because they (a) take up a slot which in other hours is used by a regional train, (b) receive subsidies from the state or regional transport provider, due to (c) a contract between DB Fernverkehr and the state/region. Demand does not really play in, rather it is the states/regions deciding that they want to co-opt the long-distance train in question.

Comment: (That's also why most of them cannot be used with the €9 ticket: DB Fernverkehr said they want money. Between Stuttgart and Singen, the transportation minister of Baden-Württemberg personally had to negotiate with DB Fernverkehr to reach an agreement. Other states did not go through the trouble or were unsuccessful in their negotiations.)

Comment: @CSM Nitpick: There are only 12 *Ländertickets:* the city states belong to the Brandenburg (Berlin)/Lower Saxony (Bremen and Hamburg) tickets; and Rhineland-Palatinate and the Saarland have a combined ticket. Also, the other big difference is that a Länderticket is always valid in IC trains classified as RE's while the €9 ticket is generally not.

Comment: @Jan I based that statement on this article, which when I wrote the answer could not find and thus quoted from memory. [2022-05-30: Warum das Neun-Euro-Ticket auf drei RE-Linien in der Region nicht gilt | rbb24](https://www.rbb24.de/panorama/beitrag/2022/05/berlin-brandenburg-neun-euro-ticket-re17-re28-re56-linien-intercity.html) *The reason: An intercity line on these routes cannot be operated economically [tagesschau.de].*

Answer (score 3):

> What's the catch?

This offer is **temporary**.

This offer is part of a package to make life cheaper for everyone, to (partly) offset high energy prices and cost of living.  During the same time, driving is also cheaper for those driving petrol or diesel (and maybe gas, not sure) due to a tax reduction.  I think drivers of electric cars have no price reduction.  The ~10% reduction in petrol prices costs the federal government more than the €9-ticket.

Secondly, this offer is also seen as a promotional act to get people back on the train after traveller numbers did not bounce back to pre-pandemic levels when pandemic restrictions were mostly gone, although this is not the official motivation.

Comment: The text from the original anouncement in March:' [2022-02-22: Energiepreise: Ampel beschließt 300 Euro Einmalzahlung – Tanken wird günstiger | ZEIT ONLINE](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2022-03/energiepreise-ampel-beschliesst-300-euro-steuerliche-energiepauschale) *As a further measure to relieve the burden on citizens, Ricarda Lang announced **support for people who depend on local public transport**: here, tickets for nine euros per month should be available nationwide – also for a limited period of three months, she said.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson Edited.

Comment: The point is that they are other packages that have nothing to do with the 9€ ticket. The temporary **tax** reduction for petrol and the one time €300 have nothing to do with the 9€ ticket.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Politically, with the current government, one would be impossible without the other.  Therefore, they have everything to do with each other.

Comment: You may think so, but in reality it is only a short term measure to reduce costs. A similar action was the VAT reduction during the second half 2020 after the lockdown to encourage spending.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I wrote in my answer that it is only a short term measure, so I'm not sure what point you are trying to make.  Politically, FDP wanted lower fuel prices, Greens wanted cheap public transportation, and SPD was fine with both.  But Greens would never have agreed with lower fuel prices without spending a comparable amount on public transport, and as it happens, the monthly taxpayer cost of the €9-ticket is similar to the monthly taxpayer cost to reducing fuel prices to the EU minimum.

Comment: The OP is not interested in the politics, thus that is off topic. The question is only asking if they are eligible.

Comment: Because the pandemic is not over, and people who are paying attention know this.  I say from a pizza place where maskless Karen and Ken just picked up 12 whole pizzas. While 3 people in the whole store had masks (credit to karen, who donned one on the sight of me).

Comment: I’ve asked a follow up question that’s somewhat related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174049/are-masks-still-mandatory-on-any-german-long-distance-trains