# Are masks still mandatory on any German long distance trains?

Tags: trains, germany, covid-19

Deutsche Bahn states:

> DB has an urgent request to make of all passengers: when you are on a train, please be responsible and considerate by wearing a mask (medical-grade or FFP2), maintaining social distance and complying with hygiene regulations. **Please note the regulations in force in Germany's different federal states.**

Is there a map/list somewhere or which federal states still require masking for long distance train journeys?

Context: I’m planning to travel around Germany next week. If any train rides still require masking I will rent a car instead of using public transport.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136875/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-are-masks-still-mandatory-on-any-german-l).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update Summer 2023:**

No more masks necessary.

**Update December 2022:**

Long distance trains: FFP2 mask.

Local public transport: at least medical masks. Exception: no masks in Bavaria and Sachsen-Anhalt.

Airplanes: no masks

Sources:

- https://www.adac.de/news/coronavirus/
- https://www.bahn.com/en/booking-information/corona

---

As of June 2022, for public transport, you need at least a medical mask in:

> Baden-Württemberg,
> Bremen,
> Hessen,
> Mecklenburg-Vorpommern,
> Nordrhein-Westfalen,
> Rheinland-Pfalz,
> Saarland,
> Sachsen,
> Sachsen-Anhalt,
> Schleswig-Holstein,
> Thüringen.

You need a FFP2 mask in:

> Bayern,
> Berlin,
> Brandenburg,
> Hamburg,
> Niedersachsen.

Source (in German): https://www.24rhein.de/leben-im-westen/verkehr/9-euro-ticket-maskenpflicht-maske-corona-regeln-oepnv-bundesland-orte-bahn-zug-bus-91575875.html

Comment: Wow, looks like most of Germany is still covered by the mask thing. Car rental it is then.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Outside of public transport, it depends on regional trends. In some areas, most still wear a mask when shopping, in others there are only a few.

Comment: I presume the places listed also mandate masks in all indoors areas still? Voluntary masking is not a problem for me, only law enforced one.

Comment: @JonathanReez By law, masks are mandatory in public transport and hospitals etc. Other places make up their own rules. In some tourist attractions (e.g. Herrenchiemsse) you have to wear a mask. Shops usually don't because they will loose customers. When in doubt, check the website.

Comment: When entering a shop, restaurants or public transport there are signs (often with pictograms) at the door showing what is expected. These are presently based on the individual house rules.

Comment: (cont'd) ... before you drive to a remote location.

Comment: In case people weren't keeping count that is all 16 states.

Comment: Many pharmacies still require masks too.

Comment: Can you take off your mask on a long distance train as soon as it enters Bavaria or Sachsen-Anhalt?

Comment: @JonathanReez no. It does not depend on where you are physically but on the type of train. Long-distance train regulations are set by the federal government, and in the federal government there is Mr Lauterbach who would make masks permanent if he could. Regional trains are governed by the states (Länder) and there Bayern and Sachsen-Anhalt have removed the mask mandate.

Comment: I took a bus in Baden-Württemberg yesterday and no one was wearing a mask, so this is outdated.

Comment: See also: [Coronavirus: Informationen der Bundesländern | Bundesregierung](https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/themen/coronavirus/corona-bundeslaender-1745198): *The last Corona protection measures expired on April 7, 2023.*

Answer (score 1):

This answer is now outdated.

From [DB's website](https://www.bahn.com/en/booking-information/safe-travel):

> Please wear an FFP2 or medical-grade mask when travelling on our long-distance trains.
> Anyone who fails to do so can be barred from travelling and be fined.

Comment: "Anyone who fails to do so can be barred from travelling and be fined." sounds like more than a polite request to me.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, which could be misunderstood. As of yesterday, the DB wrote for a train between separate states "mask requirement according to legal regulation; we advise a FFP2 mask." Each of the 16 states has defined what mask is required.